# Retain 0's when incrementing number

Tags: ruby

If I increment integer `003` by `1`, I get `4`.

```
num = 003
num += 1
# => 4
```

I want it to be `004`. How can I retain the `0`'s in this?

Comment: Not clear what you mean.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Maybe it's getting late over here because I thought it was super straightforward?  @sawa Thanks

Comment: @Bitwise it's unclear, because integers don't have leading zeros, i.e. there is no integer `003` and no integer `004`. The literal `003` is equivalent to `03` which means _octal_ number `3`. And that is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an integer to a String and give it a fixed amount of padding using `String#rjust`, where the first argument is the total width of the resulting String, and the second argument is the character to use for padding:

```
>> int = 3
>> str = int.to_s.rjust(3, '0')
#=> "003"
```

And then you can increment that string using `String#next`:

```
>> str.next
#=> "004"
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. "You can't have an integer with value 003" contradicts with `int = 003; int # => 3`. You **can** have such integer. Also, just stating "[y]ou lose those leading zeros and the variable retains only the integer value" is wrong. It it not simply cutting off the leading zeros. That is not the way it works. `009` does not mean `9`. See mu is too short's answer.

Comment: @sawa Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the leading zero in `003` makes that an octal integer literal in Ruby, not a decimal. Of course, it doesn't matter with `3` but it does matter for `009` (which is a `SyntaxError`), `030`, etc. Presumably you really mean to say:

```
num = 3
```

as the leading zeroes aren't really part of the number, they're just formatting that you want on output. To format the number, you'd use [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) or [`sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
> '%03d' % 3
=> "003" 

> sprintf('%03d', 3)
=> "003"
```